# Alphabetical value

Tags: java, string, letters

> Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string,
>   except we'll accept any letter for the 'd', so "cope" and "cooe" count.

Is there a value that I can input that means any letter or do I have to make a case for every letter of the alphabet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions on Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938067/regular-expressions-on-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
string.matches("co[a-z]e")
```

To count the number of matches:

```
int count = 0;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("co[a-z]e").matcher(string);
while(m.find()) {
    count++;
}
```